# Deploy OSGi using JBoss in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, osgi, jboss7.x

I am trying to learn how to implement OSGi using JBoss 7 and Eclipse. I am trying to find out how to do it by using Maven. I have already created a bundle and converted it to a deployable jar file. Now I want to deploy it. Through my search on internet, especially the JBoss.org, I am getting how to create a pom.xml file etc. But when it comes to creating a new Maven project in Eclipse, I am unable to proceed further. I don't expect a direct solution here. I would be glad if some one can point me to an appropriate tutorial. I have failed to search on internet. If any more information is required from my side, please feel free to comment.